# Is there a settings file which will configure shortcuts for ALL Visual Studio and ReSharper commands

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0

I love shortcuts. Currently I have to configure many of the shortcuts manually in Visual Studio/ReSharper because by default many commands don't have keyboard shortcuts.

**Is there any way to configure shortcuts for ALL commands?** I really want to avoid having to set shortcuts manually, but would rather have them pre-configured and I would just learn them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to script/otherwise automate setting up all custom shortcuts.

What I had done long ago is to **Export** (via Tools - Import and Export Settings) your keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio once you've set them. Then, store the resulting **.vssettings** somewhere accessible (like Dropbox), and if you ever lose your shortcuts, you can always re-import them.

Export dumps out all shortcuts, including those set by 3<sup>rd</sup>-party tools. In addition, since Visual Studio 2013, it's possible to synchronize your settings (including shortcuts) with the [online profile](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/08/visual-studio-2013-tips-cloud-sync.html).

Comment: Thanks Igal. I already export the settings files and store it on my Google Drive :)

I wish there was some website where people could share their settings files, much like https://studiostyl.es/ but for shortcuts/etc